# Facebook app platform: Mac

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to submit my app for review, but I get the following warning:
[image]
When I navigate to the settings tab and want to add a platform, the following platforms are available:
[image]

My app is for OS X, which is obviously missing here. So what to select? If I select "Website" I get a rejection because my app is not a web app.

Facebook doesn't have a real developer support and their feedback messages barely contain information. Is there any way to contact the reviewers?

Comment: Desktop apps are supposed to be submitted as platform “Website”, assuming they use a web view for login purposes – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/requirements#platforms Just make it very clear in review instructions, that this is not a website but a desktop app, and provide them with appropriate means the see what your app does and how it works (like a screencast/video).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it again and hope to not get another rejection.